# focus on UITextField inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios7, touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a custom UICollectionViewCell that contains a UITextField inside of it which is only accessible when the cell is selected.  The CollectionView has multi select enabled and the problem is that when trying to select the UITextField to type in it, the cell is deselected instead of giving the TextField focus.

How do I allow focus on the UITextField inside of the CollectionViewCell without causing the cell to be deselected?

Note: I've also tried adding buttons to the cell template and the button actions are not getting called either.  It seems as though the cell itself is capturing all of the touch events and not passing them along to child views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original problem was, but I solved it by re-creating the UICollectionViewCell interface inside the UICollectionView in my storyboard instead of loading it from a different .xib file.

Comment: and How did you access the UiTextView from your controller?